# VSCode Intellisense in angular with standalone components

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've recently migrated a medium sized project to angular standalone components. I do like it and see a lot of advantages in this approach.

But, one thing bothers me a lot, working with VSCode I no longer have autocomplete when writing templates, since I havent imported the dependency in the component. I would really like if it would autocomplete then auto-import the dependency. I would also love if it would also remove unused imports (seems more complex). I've noticed that if a type the component there is a "quick fix" option that adds the missing import, but works only for tags, and I still need to write the full tag.

I've read somewhere that WebStorm handles it, but it is not an option atm. How are teams handling this, to continue coding efficiently?

Comment: Sad it seems there's no solution yet..